# Hyperledger Fabric Java Daemon

Tags: java, blockchain, hyperledger

I am currently digging into development with Hyperledger Fabric and here is what I need to do:

I have a SpringBoot daemon that realizes a REST interface for pushing and pulling certain data to/from the ledger. This daemon should now run the Hyperledger-Fabric, meaning I would "use" the ledger running "inside" the daemon as if it was a local data-dump or so.

Following the taxonomy of http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/arch-deep-dive.html, it would be a "peer".

The aim is to have a private (yes, that's intentional by design) blockchain, not connect to some existing network.

Unfortunately, apparently all examples so far exist for building/running/using a hl-f standalone instance, predominantly via Docker. How would I run such a SpringBoot with the Java-SDK of Hyperledger Fabric?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with SpringBoot, but you can build the Peer as native rather than Docker image. Look at the Makefile, it has option "- peer - builds a native fabric peer binary"

make -peer

I am assuming that with a native executable, you can start it up from SpringBoot daemon and communicate with the Peer via GRPC or the Fabric Java SDK.